# Free Partition Table Editor?

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning

Is there any free program out there that lets you **manually** edit partition table(s) (**including** the *extended* partitions -- not just primary)?

Comment: gparted, parted, every Linux live-cd in existence... for a trio of disk tools, look at gparted, clonezilla, and test disk.

Comment: Sure. It's called a hex editor.

Comment: @Hello71: I have no idea what the partition table format on the disk is, so a hex editor is useless. (I think you already knew that, though. -__- )

Comment: Boot off just about any Linux CD, run `fdisk`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that [PTEdit](http://paulski.com/zpages.php?id=2103) is able to edit the MBR information.

Comment: Does it handle extended partitions?

Comment: Well, the screenshot *does* have a "Go to EPBR" button. (I haven't actually tested the software myself, though. Using GPT here.)

Comment: oooo that looks interesting, I'd missed that; I'll give it a try. +1

Comment: Oh dear... I'm reading [the information](http://paulski.com/zpages.php?id=2102) and it looks like the logical partitions (as compared to primary ones) are *much* more complicated than I imagined. Wish I could +1 again, that is such a useful page...

Comment: You'd think I'd have learned how the SE sites work [by now](http://stackoverflow.com/users/541686/mehrdad)...

Comment: @Mehrdad: Good point.

Comment: That is one scary looking piece of software, I see many backups taking place before use.

Comment: The tool links are dead now.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: In the interest of improving the results for people that may end up here wrongly, I have learned today that there is a difference between *partitions* and *partition tables*. [This wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_table) on partition tables begins to explain the difference; that article leads to this one on the [Master Boot Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record), which is the term I'm more familiar with.

**Original Answer**: [Easeus](http://www.partition-tool.com/) has a partition tool that is free. It works great, and can do a lot of things that the pay-for tools can do. I've used it a lot, many people like it.

You can adjust the primary and logical partitions, choose how much to leave in the existing partition before making a new one, and can even set it up in your main OS and have it configure it on reboot. Super handy tool.

Comment: Are you sure it's a partition table editor and not just a partition manager?

Comment: It does edit the partition table, just not the way old diskprobe tools allowed you to do it manually, it is an automated edit depending on what you choose to do in the Easeus software. Aggie proof in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parted, and gparted are quite good tools.  You can find them on the [parted magic cd](http://partedmagic.com).

Comment: Really? They let you manually play around with the partition table? So e.g. I can use it to re-order my EPBR entries to my liking? I didn't know that..

Comment: @Mehrdad no, that wasn't part of your question.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading but my question literally stated "**manually** edit partition table".

Comment: @Mehrdad: "re-order my EPBR entries to my liking"? Just...why?

Comment: @grawity: Because some programs (notably Partition Magic) complain if they're not in a particular order.

Comment: @Mehrdad pretty much all partition tools are manual tools; it is generally frowned upon for a program to rearrange your partitions automatically without your input.

Comment: @psusi: I think you missed the point of my question then. :\

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded **Active@ Disk Editor** from /www.disk-editor.org

- Free as in beer.
- Works on Win8.1 x86, claimed support for all modern Windows
- Provided Linux application too, did not tried
- Has both modes for MBR editing - PTEdit-like "table with cells", and Hex Editor with templates tree in left panel.

At the same time,

- Somewhat heavy on UI, i wonder if it uses HTML inside, like it is trendy today.
- In Hex mode sync'ing between hex dump main panel and templated view on the left is broken, or counter-intuitive at least.

I wanted to change order of two partitions, without actually moving any data.

I ended with manually selected data blobs in "hex dump" panel.
The user selection is not visible, so was feeling very flaky!

The tree on the left handily shows "partition entry" structures, and highlight them in the panel, but does NOT provide for "select this block entirely", only manual mouse selection.

So i did the swap, copied part1 into part3, then part2 into part1, then part3 into part2, then zeroed part 3.

After those copy-pastes in HEX dump - the data in the left tree DID NOT update itself. Very confusing.

Yet some time later as i went on with my actions - it suddenly caught up and updated itself.

I failed to find any pattern in this, i wished to trigger the syncronization of panels, but could not.

**However** While GUI problems this tool seems to work.